# NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentFactoryResolver (Angular v6)

Tags: angular, tsconfig, angular-library

**Goal**: I have the main application and a Library. I need to be able to test that library with the main application in real time. In other words, I need to be able to build my library and the main application recognizes a change immediately (don't want to push to npm with every change).

**Error** When I try to run the main application with the following setup I get this error.

> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[PrmCompiler ->
>   ComponentFactoryResolver]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentFactoryResolver! ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PrmCompiler ->
>   ComponentFactoryResolver]:

**Setup**: I am using `paths` in the tsConfig to reference the library

```
"compilerOptions": {
     "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@stud/myLibrary": ["../librarys/dist/MyLibrary"],
    }   
}
```

I build the library using `prod: true` and `aot: true`

Here is tsconfig.lib.ts in the library.

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "flatModuleId": "AUTOGENERATED",
    "flatModuleOutFile": "AUTOGENERATED",
    "preserveSymlinks": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.stubs.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have `preserveSymlinks` set to true. (several places has said to do that but it doesn't work)

Here is the angular.json for the lib.

```
 "myLibrary": {
  "root": "projects/myLibrary",
  "sourceRoot": "projects/myLibrary/src",
  "projectType": "library",
  "prefix": "prm",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "projects/myLibrary/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "project": "projects/myLibrary/ng-package.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "project": "projects/myLibrary/ng-package.prod.json"
        }
      }
    },
 ....
 }
```

If I publish the app it works fine, it only seems to be an issue if I try to access it using `paths`.